# Postgres Select where arrays have equal values but no specific order

Tags: sql, postgresql

Trying to query for values in a table, where two arrays have the same value, but not necessarily in the same order.

given: a column with a value of

```
{'first', 'second'}
```

expected:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE array_column = {'second', 'first'}
```

expected:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE array_column = {'second'}
```

result 1

```
{'first', 'second'}
```

result 2:  nothing

I can sort the input array I am querying with, but I cannot guarantee that the database will have those arrays stored in that same order. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html) "*Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be a sign of database misdesign.*"

Comment: You are probably looking for the overlaps operator `&&`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was thinking about just using the overlap operator, and then doing exact comparison in code but I wasn't sure if Postgres offers a way to do this through a query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the following data structure:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  array_column TEXT[]
);

INSERT INTO my_table ( id, array_column ) VALUES ( 1, ARRAY['first'] );
INSERT INTO my_table ( id, array_column ) VALUES ( 2, ARRAY['first','second'] );
INSERT INTO my_table ( id, array_column ) VALUES ( 3, ARRAY['first','second','third'] );
```

Combining the *contains operator* (`@>`) and the *is contained by operator* (`<@`):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  my_table
WHERE
  array_column <@ ARRAY['second','first'] AND
  array_column @> ARRAY['second','first'];
```

Output:

```
| id | array_column |
|----|--------------|
|  2 | first,second |
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4c5e7/1)

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use the "contains" operators:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM my_table t
WHERE array_column <@ array('second', 'first') and
      array_column @> array('second', 'first')
```